# RC timing circuit using a 2N3904

Tags: remote-control, network

I have a 12VDC source driving an LED thru a 2.4K resistor.  When a 12VDC control turns on I want power the base of a 2N3094 thru an RC network to drop the LED voltage to 0 in .5 to 1 second.  I understand the inverter circuit, but not the RC network driving the base of the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a circuit like this, where the transistor "steals" the current from the LED.  This would be an excellent candidate for breadboarding to finalize component values.  The base of Q1 is supplied through V2 for the purposes of simulation but can also be a switch or something connected to V1.  R2 can't be too large or it won't turn D1 off completely, which leaves you with a bit of a bulky capacitor.  A comparator would allow you to use a larger R and smaller C and give you a sharper cutoff, but this works with a single transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnNjYI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image: output graph]

Answer (score 0):

Can't draw a schematic right now; I might be able to add one later.  For now, start with the vir schematic:

Move D1 so it is in the Q1 collector circuit, the place held by AM2

Delete V2.

Add a 1K resistor between the Q1 base and C1.

Disconnect the bottom of C1 from GND.

Connect C1 between the Q1 base and V1. (Reverse C1 for correct polarity.)

Connect the left end of R1 go GND.

When power is applied, the voltage across C1 is zero.  This pulls the Q1 base resistor up to V1, turning Q1 on as a saturated switch.  As C1 charges up through R2, the voltage at the Q1 base slowly decreases.  When it drops below 0.6 V, Q1 turns off, turning off the LED.

0.6 V is 5% of 12 V.  Thus, when Q1 starts to turn off, the voltage across C1 is 95% of V1.  In an R-C charge or discharge circuit, 95% is the voltage reached in three R-C time constants.  With the components shown, this will happen in approx. 30 seconds.  Decrease the values of R2, C1, or both to get the time delay you want.

An R-C time constant is the product of the resistor and capacitor values, expressed in seconds.  100 uF = 0.0001 F (farads).  0.0001 x 100,000 (R2) = 10 seconds; thus, three time constants = 30 seconds.  For 1 second, start with something like 10 uF and 33K.